# Copying files without losing metadata in Linux

Tags: linux, rsync, metadata, cp

How on Linux can I copy things like music files with “Artist” and “Title” tags without losing the tags?

Will `rsync` work? Will `cp`?

Does either one need any specific switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole concept of metadata is that it is directly connected to a file. Metadata is data about data [as explained here on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata):

> Metadata is "data about data". There are two (metadata types),
>   structural metadata, about the design and specification of data
>   structures or "data about the containers of data"; and descriptive
>   metadata about individual instances of application data or the data
>   content.

So copying via `rsync`, `cp` or pretty much anything will retain all file metadata: The data structure specific stuff as well as descriptive metadata such as “Artist” and “Title” items.

That said some applications that are not on Linux—such as iTunes on Mac OS X—stores some MP3 data in the file and some in an external file called the “iTunes Library.” So copying a file in Mac OS X without copying the “iTunes Library” can result in a loss of data connected specifically to iTunes.

But that is not the same as file connected metadata. In general, metadata stays connected with the file it is associated with unless something explicitly acts on the metadata to wipe it.

Comment: So if I add these using id3tag, it should stay?

Comment: Alright, thanks. Now, if only there was a good way to autocomplete tags on Linux rather than manually doing this...

Comment: @user365967 Late, but for the benefit of future readers: MusicBrainz Picard can automate a lot of the tagging, or at least simplify it (e.g. by generating tags from file name patterns).